# TypeError: Extracting rows of matrix into new matrix

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have an initialised zero matrix:

```
 A = zeros(m,n)
```

And I also have another matrix, B, which has dimension kxn, where k>=m. We want to extract rows p through to q of B and make that A. We have set the dimension of the matrix of A (assumed) to be the same as q-p+1.
     When I try A[p:q,:] = B[p:q,:], Python gives me an error! How can I solve this?

e.g. Suppose we have:

```
 Q = ones((7,4))
 A = zeros((5,4))
 %want rows 2 to 6 of Q
 A = Q[1:5,]
```

Comment: Why not just `A = B[p:q,:]`?

Comment: *"Python gives me an error"* - what error? Give a [mcve].

Comment: I tried this and I get TypeError: list indices must be integers not tuples - I do have other code above it

Comment: Could you please give us all the code necessary to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Seems like you have python list instead of numpy matrix. Convert them to `numpy` object before indexing.

Comment: I didn't get error for the code you gave in python 3.5 with `from numpy import zeros, ones`.

Comment: @Psidom, ah ok, suppose I now wanted to input the average of the rows of A into an array - how could I do this?

Comment: Use the `mean()` function with axis specified as `1`(rows). `A.mean(axis = 1)`